# Modx revo 2.4.2 Get resource level

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources, modx-templates

I'm using getResource and I would like to retrieve resource's level to create conditions. I found an old script but it does not work anymore with modx 2.4.2:

```
<?php
/*GetLevel snippet */
$parentIds = $modx->getParentIds($modx->resource->get('id'))
return count($parentIds);
```

It crashes the website. Can someone help or update the code above?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It was just missing a semicolon :

```
/*GetLevel snippet */
$parentIds = $modx->getParentIds($modx->resource->get('id'));
return count($parentIds);
```